# creating a function - invalid character in identifier (python)

Tags: python

I have this problem to solve with python functions

> Write a function to_celsius(fahrenheit) that takes a float temperature
>   in degrees fahrenheit and returns the equivalent temperature in
>   degrees celsius.

and this is what I have programmed so far (they gave me the formula and I set it as 'c')

```
def to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    c = (farenheit − 32) * 59

    return c 

print(fahrenheit(0))
```

but when I run the program it says

> Syntax Error: invalid character in identifier: , line 2, pos
>   20

Comment: `fahrenheit` is the local name of the function argument, not the name of the function. `print(to_celsius(0))`

Answer (score 2):

The character you are using for subtraction is `−`. It should be `-`. (See the difference?)

One is a minus sign (incorrect) and one is a hyphen (correct).

You also have a few typos and mistakes. You misspelled "fahrenheit" once. Also, you should call the function as `to_celsius(0)`, not `fahrenheit(0)`. Another thing, `59` should be `5 / 9` if you want the correct conversion.

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
def to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    c = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9

    return c 

print(to_celsius(0))
```

Comment: Where is `−` located in keyboard?

Comment: @Partho63 Nowhere on a standard US QWERTY (or any other typical keyboard layout). Not sure how it got into OP's code.